# tf.while_loop -> Number of inputs and outputs of body must match loop_vars: 1, 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use a tf.while_loop but I got the following message :

```
ValueError: Number of inputs and outputs of body must match loop_vars: 1, 2
```

```
total_loss, i = list(), tf.constant(0)
def sampled_softmax_body(i, total_loss):
    loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=logits_weights, biases=logits_biases, labels=target, inputs=h2_decoder_outputs[:,i,:], num_sampled=n_sampled_softmax, num_classes=n_fra_words, partition_strategy="div")     
    total_loss.append(loss)
    i = i + 1
    return i, total_loss
def condition(i, total_loss):
    return True and i < max_words_per_sentence["fra"]
tf.while_loop(condition, sampled_softmax_body, [i, total_loss])
```

Comment: To someone unfamiliar with tensorflow, the fact that you're passing a list but returning a pair looks suspicious.

Comment: What do you mean ? my output args are the same as the input ones. except that total_loss has grown.

Comment: `[i, total_loss]` and `(i, total_loss)` are different shapes. Change it so you either start with `(i, total_loss)` or return `[i, total_loss]` from the body.

Comment: thanks, it helped. it did not solve entirely but it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my strategy and come with this working :

```
total_loss, i = list(), tf.constant(0)
def sampled_softmax_body(i):
    loss = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=logits_weights, biases=logits_biases, labels=target, inputs=h2_decoder_outputs[:,i,:], num_sampled=n_sampled_softmax, num_classes=n_fra_words, partition_strategy="div")     
    total_loss.append(loss)
    return tf.add(i, 1)
def condition(i):
    return i < max_words_per_sentence["fra"]
tf.while_loop(condition, sampled_softmax_body, [i])
```

but how I am supposed to get the content of `total_list` ? 
because it is transform buy the loop. I have not the appended list I created.

```
In [8]: total_loss
Out[8]: [<tf.Tensor 'while/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_2:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>]
```

My goal is to use backpropagation using `total_loss`